# What is the proper way to get a certain page's pageview in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

My doing is Behavior->Site Content->all page and then put the URL(excluding the domain name ofc) of that page in the marked area in the screenshot below

[image]

But the data I get in this way has a huge difference with what the article hit times recorded by my website. As in the screenshot, this URL has 972 pageview. However, in my database, for this article there are 3247 hits:
[image]

I understand that GA's pageview and website article hits are two different things. Refreshing the page 5 times in a short time may add 5 to the hits but won't affect GA's pageview. But I can't imagine what could make as much as four times differences. I don't think my clients would each refresh the page 4 times. Most of their behaviors should simply be open->read->close.

I've checked the time frame. It's from the day my website was published until today. I've checked my CMS, it is unlikely this article has another URL. And this GA screenshot is from a raw data view that doesn't have any filter applied.

And this article is not the only one that has such a huge differences. On my website there are many other articles that have thousands of hits while GA's page view is only about or less than 1/3 of that hit number. So, what did I miss?

Comment: The biggest difference is likely to be bots. GA doesn't get many bot hits because it is JavaScript based.   Nearly half of all website traffic is from bots.  https://www.techradar.com/news/bot-traffic-reached-a-new-high-in-2020

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks. I knew there were bots but didn't know there could be as high as 40%. But again, even if we take 40% bots pageview into consideration, the difference is still large. Anyway, I am gonna create a view that DOESN'T exclude "known bots", the result will hopefully come out by the end of the next month. :)

Comment: GA can't track most bots at all because the bots never call the tracking script.   Only server log based analytics can do that.

Comment: For small and new sites bot traffic can be several times human traffic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Guess I will have to open a new question regarding how to filter out the bots traffic from server log.

Comment: That is hard to do.  A lot of bots send a user agent that identifies them as such, but many bots try to masquerade legit browsers.